# What are the correct modifiers for a player conducting a ritual and for those assisting him in ETU

Tags: savage-worlds, rituals

I am new to Savage Worlds and new to GMing in general.  Recently, I had the pleasure of GMing the published adventure "Class Ring" for the ETU setting.  The player characters were all chosen from the published list of ETU Character Archetypes.

I am puzzled by the final showdown with the demon Solas.  To banish him, the heroes need to successfully execute the ritual Exorcismus Daemonis.  According to the stats for this ritual, it has a Casting Modifier of -4.

According to the ETU setting rules, to perform a ritual you use the ritualism skill, or if you don't have that, you use Smarts -2 with double the Casting Modifier (-8).  None of the player characters actually had ritualism and neither did the friendly NPC Dr. Peter Hyde, so it was going to have to be cast using smarts.

Dr. Peter Hyde had the highest smarts (d8) and according to his bio actually created the ritual, so it made sense for him to perform the ritual.  2 heroes with Smarts d6 assisted with the ritual (Cooperative Rolls), while two attempted to delay Solas.

My understanding from reading the rules is that everybody participating in the ritual would make their Smarts roll at -10... -2 for using smarts and -8 for the doubled casting modifier.

This seems super dooper hard.  Basically, to pull it off, the heroes would need a *lot* of aces.  In fact, the only way to get success is to ace and be lucky with your next roll.

I note that the Dean's notes to the adventure strongly suggest at least one character have the ritualism skill, something I overlooked in preparation... in hindsight, I should have ruled that Dr. Peter Hyde had ritualism... after all, he created the bloody thing.  But be that as it may, my questions still stand:

- In the scenario I describe above (no casters with Ritualism), is -10 the correct modifier to the smarts roll.
- Are heroes assisting with the ritual w/o Ritualism subject to the -10 modifier?
- Do heroes assisting with the ritual make their cooperative roll during their own turn in initiative order or do they make their cooperative roll at the same time as the hero leading the ritual.  For example, if a hero's initiative order is after the caster of the ritual, would he make is roll with the leader so that the leader might benefit from the assistant's success?  Or would the assistant roll on his turn in initiative order and his success would benefit the leader in the subsequent round?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-10 would be the correct Smarts roll modifier for an untrained ritualist.
Assistants are subject to the same modifier.
I believe it's supposed to be at the same time as the lead ritualist.

I'm sorry your group had a hard time with Class Ring at the end. Hopefully they had fun up to that point. FWIW the archetypes are meant as starting characters, meaning you'd want to level them up and give them additional skills if you're dropping them into an adventure for ranks higher than Freshmen. If I remember correctly, Class Ring is a Sophomore or Junior level adventure. It assumes the characters have already had a certain amount of exposure to the supernatural by that point.

Comment: The book says it is for 4-6 Freshman or Juniors.  Everybody in the group really loved the adventure and I found it a real pleasure to GM!  Thanks to some fudging on my part, they finally banished Solas in the nick of time.  Would have been easier if I'd read the part about making sure somebody had ritualism, but I just wanted to make sure I undersood the rules.

Comment: Make that 4-6 Freshman or Sophomores.

Comment: So, to further clarify you answer re: the cooperative rolls, @Preston... if, as you say, the assistants "assist" at the same time as the lead ritualist, do they NOT get any other actions?  Or can they take their turn in initiative order and do something else?  If so, would their actions be subject to the -2 penalty for multiple actions?

Comment: According to Clint, it is recommend that the leader and his assistants all go on the same card... accepting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Thunderforge but I believe that with Rituals in ETU, you have the choice of using either Ritualism or Smarts -2 and a doubled casting modifier.

Comment: @Thunderforge from the ETU Core Book:  "Characters can attempt to lead or participate in a ritual using Smarts -2 instead of Ritualism, but all casting modifiers are doubled!"  So, I'd say the answer is yes... I don't see why anyone would choose to roll smarts at -2 and a doubled casting modifier if they actually had ritualism.  Also, note Preston's answer above... he is one of the developers and writers of ETU and the Class Ring adventure, so he would know :)

Comment: @seanicus Thank you for clarifying that the rules clearly say you can participate, even if you do not have Ritualism (this differs from the core rules).

Comment: I think that the answerer should state in the answer that they are one of the writers of East Texas University. This was not immediately obvious to me, and I feel like it's something that should be disclosed if you give an authoritative answer on a game you made.